# Why does my bed stop heating at high temperature when the extruder starts heating?

Tags: marlin, creality-ender-5, temperature

To give some more context to my question: it does work as expected (that is the extruder start heating after the bed has reached the set temperature) when I set the bed temperature to be 70 °C or lower. The problem happens when the bed temperature is set to be 90 °C or more. Last time, I set it up to be 98 °C. It did stop heating at 95 °C, then heat the extruder normally. Once the extruder has reached the proper temperature, if I manually restart heating the bed, it works.
Last time, I saw an `M190 S0`, maybe after `G28`, not 100% sure about this, though.

I don't know if it is linked to lately updating Marlin with the latest bug fixes version. I have been searching in `configuration.h` to see if I could find something related, without success.  (Marlin on Ender 5 board V4.2.7)